# How to edit JSON data in multiple files programmatically?

Tags: java, json, jenkins

I want to edit deployment configuration json file where different server configurations will be provided.

I'm aware of converting JSON into Java objects and vice-versa. And also Xpath like querying for Json([JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)). But none of them would suit as at runtime I cannot generate Java classes and populate the values.
JsonPath helps in getting the values, what I'm looking for is setting values.

Is there any library for editing values of keys in json file?

Comment: What does this have to do with Jenkins (tagged)? I assume you want to do this as part of Jenkins build process, please explain how exactly... If doing it as Jenkins build step with external program is ok, then answer doesn't necessarily need to have anything to do with Java, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem which looks more like a job for a scripting language than for a java application.

But when you want to do it in Java, maybe json-simple could help you. It's a library which parses JSON code to key/value maps on which you can perform any map operations, like reading, adding, removing or changing the values of keys, and serialize them back to a JSON string. http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/